# Identifying which keyboard has a keystroke originated from from within Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard

Like so many enlightened developers, I spend most of my day in Emacs. Since my main computer is a laptop attached to a desktop keyboard and monitor, I have two slightly different keyboards. I'd like to make some keys have different behaviours depending on which keyboard they came from.

For instance, my laptop has next-track and previous-track keys over `F4` and `F6`. I'd like those keys to map to next-buffer and previous-buffer, but only on the laptop keyboard. When the desktop keyboard is attached, those functions already are bound to `<XF86Forward>` and `<XF86Back>`.

A simplistic approach would be to check through `lsusb` whether a given keyboard is attached or not in a wrapper function, but that seems too cumbersome (and may introduce some delays if a USB device takes too long to answer).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this information was available to Emacs in an elegent fashion. You should probably add detailed information about your OS to your question, though. If there is a good solution it is likely to be very OS-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIn the end, I went with:

```
; Useful for checking whether a given keyboard is present
(defun usb-device-connected-p (device) 
  (< 0 (length (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (x) (cl-search device x)) 
                    (split-string (shell-command-to-string "lsusb") "\n")))))
```

This way, in my `init.el`, I can set status flags according to the keyboard I have connected at the moment:

```
(if (usb-device-connected-p "Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard")
    (progn (global-set-key (kbd "<XF86Forward>") 'next-buffer)
           (global-set-key (kbd "<XF86Back>") 'previous-buffer)
           (global-set-key (kbd "<XF86Favorites>") 'buffer-menu)
           (global-set-key (kbd "<XF86HomePage>") 'buffer-menu))
)
```